# write byte list of byte list in a new text file with custom separator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a byte list of byte list and I would like write it in a text file. I would like a TAB delemiter in each element of single list and a start a new line between each list. Here an example (in real case in "list_all" were stored 500 list and each list have 18 elements):

```
list_all=[[b'32400', b'20009', b'hill'], [b'jhon', b'hero', b'dad'], [b'seven', b'man1', b'sun']]
```

The result to obtain in the text file is:

```
32400   20009   hill
jhon    hero    dad
seven   man1    sun
```

First idea is to create a for cycle but I think isn't the best way because it will analyze one row at time with a join instruction:

```
list_all=[[b'32400', b'20009', b'hill'], [b'jhon', b'hero', b'dad'], [b'seven', b'man1', b'sun']]
with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f2:
                           for i in list_all:
                                        f2.write(b' '.join(i)+b'\r\n')
```

Is there a way to make the process more fast?

Comment: You could decode the bytes to `str` and use the `csv` module. But that requires decoding (as the `csv` module can't handle `bytes` data).

Comment: And no, I don't think this'll go much faster as the bottleneck is *writing to a file*. 500 lists is not all that much.

Comment: this script should be fast enough. for an insignificant speedup, use `f2.write(b' '.join(i)); f2.write(b'\r\n`)`